# jackson-dataformat-csv: cannot serialize LocalDate

Tags: jackson, export-to-csv

When I try to serialize object containing Local date, I get following error:

> csv generator does not support object values for properties

I have JSR-310 module enabled, with `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` and I can convert the same object to JSON without problem.

For now I resorted to mapping the object to another, string only object, but it's decadent and wasteful.

Is there a way for Jackson csv mapper to acknowledge localDates? Should I somehow enable JSR-310 specifically for csv mapper?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem because of configuring mapper after schema. Make sure you are using the latest verson of jackson and its modules. This code works for me:

```
final CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false); //Optional
final CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(PojoWithLocalDate.class);
// Use this mapper and schema as you need to: get readers, writers etc.
```

No additional annotations needed in Pojo class.

Comment: Congratulations on your first accepted answer! Keep up the good work.

Comment: some important things I have noticed :
1) findAndRegisterModules is required, otherwise the error will persist
2) mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false) can be replaced by Mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
3) confirmed that no annotations are needed in Pojo class